# How to reorder date format in filename

Tags: date, powershell, rename, wildcard, filenames

I've been looking all over stackoverflow and other forums online for any help with PowerShell variables and the rename function. I've had no luck.

The filename convention I use is: CompanyName 12.31.15 FS
(The "FS" describes the content of the file, in this case financial statements). Single digit months are preceded by 3 spaces so that the "FS" always ends up in the same column visually in windows explorer.)

The date format is m.dd.yy though I would like to change it to yy.mm.dd. The problem is I have over 30 folders with myriad of files in them- Some don't follow this file naming convention but if they use the m.dd.yy format, then the filename certainly does follow the convention.

So here's what I'm looking for:

- A way to switch around only the date part of the file name from m.dd.yy to yy.mm.dd
- In so doing, to also remove 2 of the leading spaces (where there are currently 3) and only have one space between CompanyName, date, and content.
- The files must be changed in several directories within the "companies" folder

---

Examples:

Currently:

```
CocaCola 12.31.15 FS

CocaCola  6.30.15 FS
```

I want:

```
CocaCola 15.12.31 FS

CocaCola 15.06.31 FS
```

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the files using the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet. Rename it using `Rename-Item`.
To switch the date you could parse it and format it to your desired output. However you could also do everything using a `regex`:

```
$yourCompanyPath = 'C:\tmp'

$callback = {  
    param($match) 

    '{0} {1}.{2:D2}.{3} {4}' -f $match.Groups["CompanyName"].Value, 
        $match.Groups["Year"].Value,
        [int]$match.Groups["Month"].Value,
        $match.Groups["Day"].Value,
        $match.Groups["FS"].Value
}

$rex = [regex]'(?<CompanyName>\S+)\s+(?<Month>\d+)\.(?<Day>\d+)\.(?<Year>\d+)\s+(?<FS>FS)'

Get-ChildItem $yourCompanyPath | Foreach {
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ('{0}{1}' -f $rex.Replace($_.BaseName, $callback), $_.Extension)
}
```

---

**Source example:**

```
CocaCola  6.30.15 FS.csv
CocaCola 12.31.15 FS.csv
```

**Output:**

```
CocaCola 15.06.30 FS.csv
CocaCola 15.12.31 FS.csv
```

Comment: I tested out your script twice. It seems to work on the source example but it didn't work when I tried it on a folder: It didn't do anything for filenames with the leading 3 spaces. It looks like it iterated through the other dates a few extra times because the format ended up being day, year, month. It might be that I neglected to mention that the "FS" part may be more than just one word, it may contain a few more words delimited by spaces before the .filetype.

Comment: What do you want to tell me? I answered your question since the question was about files, *not*  folders.

Comment: I guess two things:
I want it to work on individual file names, even if they're nested in folders and I your script didn't work (even on the contents of just one folder). It looks like it looped over the file names too many times.